# Google calendar OAuth token API

Tags: javascript, python, google-calendar-api

I am developing an application which has a web UI which takes in the meeting details from the user and stores it in a DB. From a back end I will periodically schedule the event on the Google calendar of the organizer and the attendees list.
I am able to independently create a calendar event using APIs via python but this needs me to go to the browser to get the verification code and enter it back. 
I would like to know what Javascript APIs to use to get OAuth token and use this later to create an event via the backend.

Comment: Are you using the server side OAuth workflow?

Comment: I have a UI where I get the event details from the user, and use these details at a later time to create the event from server side. I want to know what API to use to get the OAuth token and how to re-use this token from server side.

Comment: You can try to use [Service Account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) with this. To support server-to-server interactions, first create a service account for your project in the API Console. To access user data for users in your Google Apps domain, you need to delegate domain-wide access to the service account. Then, your application prepares to make authorized API calls by using the service account's credentials to request an access token from the OAuth server. Finally, your application can use the access token to call Google APIs.